# Will extending a class load up memory?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, inheritance

In the application i'm trying to build, I have a utility class which I'm extending to use the utility methods present within.

```
@Repository("userdao")
public class UserDAO **extends baseDAO**{
    private float PROFILE_FIELD_COUNT=16.0f;
    List<UserProfile> ObjList=null;
...
...
...
```

My question is that will this extension load up all the methods into the memory? Or is it better to instantiate an object for the base class and use the methods through that object? Which is light-weighing in terms of memory consumption?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extending another class (such that there are two classes) is no different in terms of *practical* memory usage<sup>1</sup> than creating two distinct classes which are both used. Likewise, the "depth" of the extension tree does not affect the memory usage of instances.

The "memory cost" of multiple classes is inconsequential in all but the most limited embedded environments: write the cleanest cost. Independent of the choice of subtyping (it may be better to share "utility methods" through Dependency Injection and Composition), trying to cram everything into a single "DAO class" is likely wrong.

---

<sup>1</sup> There is *a* difference, see [Java Objects Memory Structure](http://www.codeinstructions.com/2008/12/java-objects-memory-structure.html) and will depend on the particular implementation.

Comment: Scenario 1 - 
userClass extends baseClass  
Scenario 2 -
Inside the userClass, i create an object of baseClass  

Either way, we are creating an object right? Still, there is a difference in memory consumption?

Comment: One object vs two objects: It Just Doesn't Matter. Developer time is more important to worry about. (Also, if using DI/IoC it is trivial to wire up a stateless utility instance between all other objects, etc.)